# See which parts of scene take up most file size

Tags: compression

I am trying to find a way to compress the size of my scene to upload it to SheepIt. How do I see which parts of my `.blend` file take up so much space?

Comment: Generally character meshes require a lot of file data.  If you turn on Statistics in the Overlays dropdown (left of viewport shading buttons), you can then select suspect mesh objects, go into Edit mode and you'll see the number of vertices, edges, faces and triangles.  Each of these is an "C++ data object" with information like location and rotation and material assignments.  You could automate a report using python, to step through each object.

Comment: In the Outliner in *Blender FIle* mode, you can also hunt for duplicates of matherials (e.g., "G8MBaseEyesMapB_1007.jpg.005" and "G8MBaseEyesMapB_1007.jpg.007", and get into the Render editor to discover that you can consolidate references (see User Count increase) and then save/reload, and perhaps need to delete these duplicates.  Similar for Objects and other categories that are in your file.

Comment: For objects with large mesh data counts (vertices, edges, etc) you may be able to Edit, Select All (vertices) and then "Mesh >> Clean Up >> decimate (or dissolve) some geometry without making too much difference in animation or rendering quality.  You'd have to test to see if Armature parenting remains sound.

Comment: SheepIt can only render the Scene you chose before saving the file.  If you have other scenes, delete these from your "farm" version of the file, which could reduce data significantly (unless many objects were linked).